# Building time takes forever

Tags: performance, android-studio, debugging, build.gradle, building

I'm developing an android app using android studio, when using building variant debug, building time is around 3 to 5 minutes, i changed it to release to get my apk to launch the app on Google play, but it's taking forever to build, 3 hours until now and counting
What can be done??

Comment: Note: i looked up online solutions but didn't find any, all are talking about building with debug as a build variant but that's working fine in my case

Comment: Are you using any annotation processors such as The Checker Framework? How big is your app? How many gradle files do you have?

Comment: No I'm not using any annotation processors, the app has 5 activities with total of approximately 1000 lines of code if that's what you mean, and there's 6 gradle files